# Allocate space in struct for char* array

Tags: arrays, struct, char

I am trying to allocate space inside a struct. This struct contains information of a network packet.

The structure:

```
struct STRUCT_SVC_ROOM_CREATE
{
    PacketHeader Header;
    unsigned char TitleLength;
    char* RoomTitle = new char[TitleLength];
    short SuddenFactor;
    short GameModeFactor;
    unsigned char Password[4];

    int MaxMen;
};
```

See this two lines of code

**unsigned char TitleLength;**

**char* RoomTitle = new char[TitleLength];**

1st -> The length of text (**1** byte)

2nd -> The text itself    (**TitleLength** bytes)

And this is how I create the struct based into another.

```
STRUCT_SVC_ROOM_CREATE* RoomCreate = (STRUCT_SVC_ROOM_CREATE*)pHeader;
```

pHeader is another struct, this contains all the information. Then I put into another struct to get the right data location.

But it doesnt work. So the question: How to allocate space correctly and build the struct char* with the size specified in *TitleLength*?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt initialise the object inside the struct definition.

```
struct STRUCT_SVC_ROOM_CREATE
{
    PacketHeader Header;
    unsigned char TitleLength;
    char* RoomTitle;
    short SuddenFactor;
    short GameModeFactor;
    unsigned char Password[4];

    int MaxMen;
};

void someFunction()
{
   STRUCT_SVC_ROOM_CREATE* foo = new STRUCT_SVC_ROOM_CREATE;
   foo->TitleLength = 10;
   foo->RoomTitle = new char[foo->TitleLength];

}
```

Here is the requested class implementation (not tested):

```
class SVC_ROOM_CREATE{

private:
    PacketHeader Header;
    char* RoomTitle;
    short SuddenFactor;
    short GameModeFactor;
    unsigned char Password[4];

    int MaxMen;

public:
    SVC_ROOM_CREATE(PacketHeader packet_header, int length, short sud_factor, short gm_factor, unsigned char pwd[], int max)
    {
        Header = packet_header;
        RoomTitle = new char[length];
        SuddenFactor = sud_factor;
        GameModeFactor = gm_factor;
        memcpy( Password, pwd, sizeof(Password));
        MaxMen = max;
    }


};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    PacketHeader Header;
    unsigned char bar[4] = "pas";
    int TitleLength = 10;
    int SuddenFactor = 1;
    int GameModeFactor = 2;
    int MaxMen = 15;
    SVC_ROOM_CREATE* foo = new SVC_ROOM_CREATE(Header, TitleLength, SuddenFactor, GameModeFactor, bar, MaxMen);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see it. But how am I going to know the value of TitleLenght If I havent yet put the data into struct?

Comment: Well, you put data in TitleLength first. Why are you using a struct and not a class ?

Comment: I think you should read a bit more about classes. It's not that different than the structure but it will give you useful functionality like the "constructor".